# strange revert on proxy pattern delegate call

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, contract-upgrading

I've worked with upgradeable contracts before using zeppelin's upgradeable contract pattern.
However, I found out that if I try to fetch the implementation contract address through a contract call, I get an unexpected revert.

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0;

contract Proxy {
    address registry = 0xc5c97AAd92a962396229cbC8392e62585B04DfB3; // assume this is registry address

    function implementation() public view returns(address) {
        return Registry(registry).getImplementationAddress();
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        address implementationAddress = implementation();
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, returndatasize(), calldatasize())
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), implementationAddress, ptr, calldatasize(), returndatasize(), returndatasize())
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, returndatasize())

            switch result
            case 0 {revert(ptr, returndatasize())}
            default {return(ptr, returndatasize())}
        }
    } 
}

contract Registry {
    address public implementationAddress = 0x8750c1719E32294260e596c80a04818533e2C643; // assume this is impl address

    function getImplementationAddress() public view returns(address) {
        return implementationAddress;
    }
}

contract Foo { // assume this is implementation contract
    uint256 public a;
    uint256 public b;
    function setA(uint256 val) external {
        a = val;
    } 
    function setB(uint256 val) external {
        b = val;
    } 
    function getA() external view returns(uint256) { 
        return a;
    } 
    function getB() external view returns(uint256) {
       return b;
    } 
}
```

all transactions would revert on any call to the proxy in the context of `Foo`. However if I make the line `address registry = 0xc5c97AAd92a962396229cbC8392e62585B04DfB3`  constant, it would no longer revert. Does anyone have any insight into what's causing the revert?

reproduced on Solc version 0.6.13, 0.7.4.

Comment: What does "if I make the line `address registry = 0xc5c97AAd92a962396229cbC8392e62585B04DfB3` constant" mean?

Comment: `address constant registry = 0xc5c97AAd92a962396229cbC8392e62585B04DfB3`
this is what I meant, but on second check that's actually wrong. the tx still reverts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, calling another contract before changes the returndatasize.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/45739)

Comment: @ShaneFontaine It kinda answers the question, assuming `returndatasize()` is zero before a call is not always true.

Comment: @ShaneFontaine I am the author